# mysql where column = all posible values

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to do something like this? Give the $variable a default value to make mysql return all the rows?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ?;

bind_param('i', $variable);
```

It's not as stupid as it sounds... I need to filter content based on user input, so If user does not fill the input/select the value will be `ALL` (or the correct answer). I wouldn't like to print php variables inside the `prepare()` or make the default variable all the possible values. What is the correct way to do this?

I'm actually doing this:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(' SELECT t1.id, t2.*
                               FROM ' . $table . ' t1
                               INNER JOIN property t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
                               WHERE t2.use = ?
                               ' . $city_cond
                                 . $zone_cond . '
                               LIMIT ?, ?'))
```

But I wouldn't like to print inside the `prepare()` so I ask if is there any way to do it with the `bind_param()` and declaring a default value.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table` , it select all column already

Comment: why not just use `SELECT * FROM table`?

Comment: Sorry if the explanation was not clear. The variable inside the bind_param will contain a value to filter, but if the user didn't fill the input the variable will have a default value.

Comment: In that case, the answer is `$column=="" ? "SELECT * FROM table" : "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = $column"` (corrected for SQL injection of course)

Comment: Yes, well it's not that easy when the actual query is something bigger

Comment: @ChazyChaz then you need to explain the `something bigger` part so we can help

Comment: Then edit the question with the actual query, so we can see what the problem is!

Comment: Yes sorry, I thought mysql could do this... I edited.

Comment: this might be out of topic, it might be better to redesign the prepare statement so it wont have much constraint in the future..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this for similar problems:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE cond1 = ?';
$sqlparams = array('cond1');
if (!empty($column) && $column != 'ALL') {
    $sql .= ' AND column = ?';
    $sqlparams[] = $column;
}
// add more conditions, ORDER BY, LIMIT etc.
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($sqlparams);
```

Differences with mysqli (untested):

```
-    $sqlparams[] = $column;
+    $sqlparams[] = array('s', $column);
---
-$stmt->execute($sqlparams);
+foreach ($sqlparams as $sqlparam) {
+    $stmt->bind_param($sqlparam[0], $sqlparam[1]);
+}
+$stmt->execute();
```

Maybe this can be done with named parameters and always bind, needed or not.

Another approach:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE cond1 = ? AND (1 = ? OR column = ?)';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', (empty($column) ? 1 : 0));
$stmt->bind_param('s', $column);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Are you using PDO right? I didn't think I could do this with mysqli.

Comment: @ChazyChaz mysqli supports prepared statements

Comment: But it doesn't support arrays?

Comment: Yes, I use PDO (and with postgres mostly). I've added a few changes, maybe not the nicest code but should(!) work. I've added an alternative way, too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the examples, I can now make it work.

Comment: possible missing semi-colon `$sqlparams[] = $column`

Comment: @clemens321 nice. Lovin' that ternary too.